Can't make SafetySettings of VertexAI Gemini API work
I'm working on a RAG application using VertexAI API.
One of my questions has the word "roubar" and it keeps triggering the safety filter, like:
...
Candidate:
{
  "index": 0,
  "finish_reason": "SAFETY",
  "safety_ratings": [
    {
      "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH",
      "probability": "NEGLIGIBLE",
      "probability_score": 0.059326172,
      "severity": "HARM_SEVERITY_NEGLIGIBLE",
      "severity_score": 0.10986328
    },
    {
      "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT",
      "probability": "MEDIUM",
      "blocked": true,
      "probability_score": 0.69921875,
      "severity": "HARM_SEVERITY_MEDIUM",
      "severity_score": 0.45703125
    }
...

Following the VertexAI documentation, I tried to disable HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT or change it to filter only HIGH.
This is my code:
import os
import json

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import vertexai
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel, GenerationConfig, SafetySetting

from promtps import SUBJECT_PROMPT, SYSTEM_PROMPT_3
from utils import VectorDB



load_dotenv()



# Configs ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vertexai.init(
    project=os.environ["VERTEXAI_PROJECT_ID"],
    location=os.environ["VERTEXAI_REGION"]
)

safety_settings = [
    SafetySetting(
        category=SafetySetting.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT,
        threshold=SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
    )
]


# RAG flow -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def subject_identifier(query: str):
    """
    Classify the query subject.
    """
    generation_config_subject = GenerationConfig(
        response_mime_type="text/plain", 
        temperature=0
    )
    model_subject = GenerativeModel(
        model_name=os.environ["VERTEXAI_MODEL"], 
        system_instruction=SUBJECT_PROMPT
    )
    response = model_subject.generate_content(query, generation_config=generation_config_subject)

    return response.text.strip()


def retrieve(subject: str, query:str):
    """
    Retrive documents for the given query.
    """
    vector_db = VectorDB(database_directory=f"data/db/{subject}")
    chroma_collection = vector_db.get_or_create_chroma_collection()

    results = chroma_collection.query(query_texts=[query], n_results=4)
    
    return results['documents']


def generate(query):
    """
    Embbeds the retrived documents into SYSTEM_PROMPT and generate answers for the given query.
    """
    subject = subject_identifier(query=query)
    retrieved_documents = retrieve(subject=subject, query=query)

    generation_config = GenerationConfig(
        response_mime_type="application/json", 
        temperature=0
    )

    model = GenerativeModel(
        model_name=os.environ["VERTEXAI_MODEL"],
        system_instruction=SYSTEM_PROMPT_3.format(context=retrieved_documents),
    )

    response = model.generate_content(
        query, 
        generation_config=generation_config,
        safety_settings=safety_settings
    )
    
    return json.loads(response.text)

Am I doing something wrong?

Based on your screenshot “roubar” triggered SafetySettings under the category of dangerous content with probability of medium. The setting filter must be set to OFF or Block few. The code must be like this, threshold=SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.OFF or threshold=SafetySetting.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH instead of .BLOCK_NONE to avoid triggering safety filter "probability": "MEDIUM".
According to the how to configure safety filters:
The Google Cloud console lets you configure a threshold for each safety attribute. The safety filter uses only the probability scores.
There is no option to use the severity scores. The Google Cloud console provides the following threshold values:

Off (default): No automated response blocking.

Block few: Block when the probability score is HIGH.

Block some: Block when the probability score is MEDIUM or HIGH.

Block most: Block when the probability score is LOW, MEDIUM or HIGH.


For example, if you set the block setting to
Block few for the Dangerous Content category, everything that has a high probability of being dangerous content is blocked. Anything with a lower probability is allowed. The default threshold is Block some.  

There are other categories you should apply the BLOCK_NONE safety filter:

safety_settings = {
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_CIVIC_INTEGRITY: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE
})

Take a look:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/multimodal/configure-safety-filters
Also:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/reference/python/latest/vertexai.generative_models.HarmCategory
